# Question regarding Nullstellensatz and the correspondence between radical ideals of $\Bbb C[X_1, \dots, X_n]$ and affine varieties of $\Bbb A^n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Reading currently about the Nullstellensatz and I think that I hadn't really understood the idea of the correspondence $$\Bigg\{ \text{affine varieties of } \Bbb A^n \Bigg\} \longleftrightarrow \Bigg\{\text{ radical ideals of } \Bbb C[X_1, \dots, X_n] \Bigg\}.$$

Is it so that if I pick any ideal $I \subset \Bbb C[X_1, \dots X_n]$ and consider the variety $\Bbb V(I) \subset \Bbb A^n$, then $$\Bbb I(\Bbb V(I)) =I?$$ Here $\Bbb I$ is denoting the map $V \longmapsto \Bbb I(V)$ and $\Bbb V$ the map $I \longmapsto \Bbb V(I)$.

What I thought was that I have the equality $$\Bbb I(\Bbb V(I)) =\sqrt{I}$$ but by the correspondence it would look like $I = \sqrt{I}$, i.e., $I$ is a radical ideal?

**Edit**: The motivation for the question arises from problems of similar nature to the one described below.

> Determine the ideal $I(V)$ of $V(XY^3 + X^3Y - X^2 +Y)$ and $V(X^2Y, (X-1)(Y+1)^2)$.

And I was wondering why I don't have the equalities $I(V) = (XY^3 + X^3Y - X^2 +Y)$ and $I(V) = (X^2Y, (X-1)(Y+1)^2).$

Comment: It depends on the level of sophistication you're working at. If you are thinking of $\Bbb A^n$ as $\Bbb C^n$ with the Zariski topology and you're only concerned with the underlying set, then $I(V(I))=\sqrt{I}$. If you think of these objects as schemes, then you do actually get $I(V(I))=I$. But that's more by design than a theorem one needs to prove.

Comment: The reason for the question was that I found an problem set online that asked me to determine the ideal $I(V)$ of $V(XY^3 + X^3Y - X^2 +Y)$ and $V(X^2Y, (X-1)(Y+1)^2)$ and I'm wondering why wouldn't $$I(V) = (XY^3 + X^3Y - X^2 +Y)$$ in the first case and the latter be $$I(V) = (X^2Y, (X-1)(Y+1)^2).$$ I don't think they want me to compute the radicals $\sqrt{(XY^3 + X^3Y - X^2 +Y)}$ etc so I assumed there was some other approach here. However as you said these are the elementary cases without schemes to the latter doesn't hold? @KReiser

Comment: See, this sort of thing is why we request that askers [provide context about how they came to a problem](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). And why don't you think you're supposed to compute the radical? You said in your post that you know $I(V(I))=\sqrt{I}$.

Comment: This is a double-edged sword. I didn't really want to post the specific problem as then I pretty likely will only get answers to the problem and not the actual question which is the real concern here. I don't gain anything about the solution for the problem, what I need is to understand why it works. As to why I don't think I should compute the radical is that I have led to believe that it's very hard to compute these radicals by hand.

Comment: You can put the two together! Knowing that this is why you're worried makes it easier to address your bigger issues. And I would say that those radicals are pretty computable by hand - you might want to spend some more time on them and think more carefully about what it means to compute a radical. For instance, if an ideal $I$ is already prime, then $\sqrt{I}=I$, right?

Comment: I made some edits to the question for possible future readers regarding these comments. Also indeed I know that if $I$ is prime, then $\sqrt{I} = I$. The way I see radicals is that we're considering all elements $r$ of the ring $\Bbb C[x,y,z]$ (in this case) and then after some $n \in \Bbb N$ for which $r^n \in I$ we're getting more and more elements in our ideal as $r^{n+1} \in I$ also.